# Wrapping functions in R similar to Python decorators

Tags: r, decorator

In my project I have a lot of functions to work with database looking like this:

```
some_function <- function(smth) {
  con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), db)
   -- something -- 
  dbDisconnect(con)
  return(smth)
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the code and write something like a Python decorator with connection and disconnetion from db?

like this:

```
@conenct-disconnect
some_funcion <- function(smth){
-- something --
}
```

Or may be another way to do it?

Comment: You might find this chapter useful which is an equivalent to Python's decorators:
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-operators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function operator

```
with_con <- function(f, db) {
  function(...) {
    con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), db)
    f(..., `con` = con)
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
  }
}

some_func <- function(query, con) {
  #so something with x and the connection
  dbGetQuery(con, query)
}


connected_func <- with_con(some_func, db)

connected_func('SELECT * FROM table')
```